# I can't install opera browser on lubuntu

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, dependencies, opera

running these commands to install opera :

to set up a key:

```
wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

to set up a repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list'

sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install opera
```

but at the end I get this message in my command terminal :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
opera : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.16) but it is not installable
     Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.15) but it is not installable
     Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good but it is not installable
     Recommends: flashplugin-nonfree
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

From the command line typing lsb_release -a says my ubuntu version is Ubuntu 17.10, but I'm using lubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] and add the Lubuntu release/version.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: I typed in sudeo apt-get -f install and then tried to install opera, but I got the same problem. My ubuntu version is Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: @weerre then why did you add "lubuntu" to the title and body if it is Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: it says im using ubuntu 17.10 in my command line in terminal when I type lsb_release-a to check my os version. But I know I'm using lubuntu, it even says lubuntu when I start up my computer in the boot loading screen. I don't know how else to check my version or if this is another bug.

Comment: It says I'm using lubuntu 17.10 when I'm prompted the logout screen. Is this a common bug for this version?

Answer (score 1):

On your terminal, run the following commands:

```
wget https://download3.operacdn.com/pub/opera/desktop/50.0.2762.45/linux/opera-stable_50.0.2762.45_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i opera-stable_50.0.2762.45_amd64.deb
```

wget: downloads *opera-stable_50.0.2762.45_amd64.deb*

dpkg: installs opera-stable using the deb file.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the snap version, Opera website recommends downloading the snap. In the terminal, do:

```
sudo snap install opera
```

You may require to install snap first before using above command, for this use the below command:

```
sudo apt install snapd
```